# eclipse c++ build error

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm having a problem with eclipse C++ juno. My project compiles and runs from command line but eclipse (juno) keeps saying there are thousands of errors. For example there's a function SetRun in my code, and eclipse mentions this error: "called Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void SetRun(?)'", whereas SetRun is of type static void SetRun (uint32_t run);

I have quite a lot of similar errors like that, where eclipse doesn't seem to understand the type of the function and puts a '?' instead.

I also have many errors like this: "symbol '*' could not be resolved."

I also have many includes that can't be resolved, although they are resolved just fine by the compiler.

I think this is all part of the same issue.

I should also note that I had this working with eclipse previously, but now everytime I open eclipse it appears that way.

If I build the project from eclipse, it build successfully.

I tried updating the index but it didn't change a thing.

What can I do to make eclipse stop telling me about these errors?

edit:

here is an example of a include that is not resolved:

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this would help, it's just an unresolved include issue, but I have edited it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually add include and symbols paths in your project preferences. Follow [**this**](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm) instructions. You can find a lot more information about it just goggling [set up include paths eclipse](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=set+up+include+path+eclipse&oq=set+up+include+path+eclipse&gs_l=hp.3...361.10126.0.10205.49.37.10.1.1.0.188.1866.36j1.37.0...0.0.yCTsE6qNUyQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=10cf558768b74769&biw=1920&bih=944).

It is normal that even though you Eclipse editor cannot resolve the path, your compiler can, because they use independent settings.

EDIT: Looks like in your case you are interested in using ns-3 in Eclipse, then you should follow [**this instructions**](http://www.nsnam.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTO_configure_eclipse_with_ns-3).

Comment: Yes I did follow that link to the letter regarding how to set up ns3 with eclipse, but it is still not resolving the includes.

Comment: I don't know what paths I should manually include either. And more importantly, and as I stated in my question, this used to work out of the box before, I am sure I didn't need to manually add include paths for it to work. I am not sure what changed though. I tried checking 'automate discovery of paths and symbols' in 'discovery options', but it's still not working.

Comment: On what operating system are you on? Try to find the file core-module.h in your system, and you will know the right path to include.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my project. Try the following:

1. Right click on the project name
2. Then Index
3. Then Freshen All Files and wait.

This worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

In the past, i had too many issues with C++ projects under Eclipse that I eventually ended up switching to another IDE. Unless you really have to work under Eclipse, i suggest you switch to another one.

Comment: Which one you suggest.. for Windows platform need to create .so from the C code ?